# In circle O two chords AB,CD are intersecting at point P

Tags: geometry

Given circle $O$, two chords $AB,CD$ are intersecting at point $P$.

$ACBD$ is a Cyclic quadrilateral and $DB\cdot BC=AD\cdot AC$

Need to prove that $DP=PB$

I tried ti play with areas of triangle but it doesn't work for me.

I'd appreciate some ideas.

Comment: Do you know [Ptolemy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy's_theorem)?

Comment: we didn't learn this theorem. can i bypass it?

Comment: @IanMateus And how do we use Ptolemy's Theorem to prove this?

Comment: It looks quite related, so I asked it. You probably don't need it, if you say you didn't learn.

Comment: Either you don't pay attention to the important order of the vertices or else there's something funny: the quadrilateral *must* be $\;ADBC\;$ or $\;ACBD\;$, but **not** $\;ABCD\;$...check this.

Comment: @DonAntonio - oops you are right! it's $ACBD$

Comment: @maroony And the rest of the info is correct or, perhaps and hopefully, something must be changed there? Pay special attention to the letters...

Comment: @DonAntonio - im really sorry, it was too small so i misread it. now everything is correct. it was $DB\cdot BC$. again sorry for that.

Comment: Nop...perhaps all is fine now and perhaps there's a solution there very, **very** hidden to me (nothing strange), but I can't see it and already tried several things. My advice: check again the whole exercise *very carefully* and be sure everything is where it must and that you didn't forget to write down some assumptions...

Comment: well, i double checked it - that's all the details there are.
hope it's solvable